# Open React Native component from Native Java Activity in Android

Tags: java, android, react-native, push-notification, onesignal

How can I open a specific component of my React Native application from an Native Android Activity in Java?

**Here is my use case:**
I'm registering a notification receiver service in my android part, an android activity(name it Activity1) is assigned in action which is immediately  opened when the notification is received(no matter app is open or closed). Now how can I open a React Native component from the Activity(Activity1)?

Comment: You must be aware of bridging. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

Comment: Native Modules can invoke Native Java code inside React Native, but my case is kinda opposite.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html

Comment: Did anyone have a solution for it ?

Comment: changed the approach later. You can  try the first answer.

Comment: Thanks @mostafizrahman . did you tried the first approach ? my case is - As a part of POC, i developed an android app(page A) and React Native app(page B). Based on the docs from 
RN team, i integrated this Android App and RN app. When i click a button in page A, RN activity is started and page B is get loaded.
Upto here all good. Now i was wondering how i can the button on page A in RN. So page A is the page made in android and how 
a button alone in that page can be in React Native.

Answer (score 0):

I read '[Integration with Android Existing Apps Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html)' 
it is open root component(using bundle), not specific component.

i have to open specific react native js component at screen-off(lock screen)

**i using [expo framework](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/).

```
   public class UnlockActivity extends ReactActivity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {
    //static constants


    //
    private ReactRootView mReactRootView;
    private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
        mReactInstanceManager = ((MainApplication) getActivity().getApplication())
                .getReactNativeHost()
                .getReactInstanceManager();
        // The string here (e.g. "MyReactNativeApp") has to match
        // the string in AppRegistry.registerComponent() in index.js
        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "LockScreen", null);

        setContentView(mReactRootView);
    }
```

## Receiver

```
public class LockScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
//Member Variable
private TelephonyManager telephonyManager   =   null;
private boolean isPhoneIdle                 =   true;

private PhoneStateListener phoneListener    =   new PhoneStateListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
    { //Member Object
        switch(state){
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE :
                isPhoneIdle = true;
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING :
                isPhoneIdle = false;
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK :
                isPhoneIdle = false;
                break;
        }
    }
};



//Construc

tor
    public LockScreenReceiver() {
    }



    //Override Method
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))
        {
            if(telephonyManager == null)
            {
                telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            }


            if(isPhoneIdle)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, UnlockActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it is a solution?

Comment: Any solution for this problem?